# error in densityplot mice- missing data example

Tags: r, missing-data, density-plot, r-mice

I have the following data:

```
dput(example)
structure(list(q1 = c(5, 22, 16, 24, 9, 20, 21, 16, 28, 28, 24, 
25, 34, 22, 29, NA, 24, 13, 10, 17, 24, 21, 22, 35, 20, 25, 25, 
23, 22, 20, 27, 22, 20, 23, 5, 21, 19, 17, 27, 20, 35, 35, 10, 
16, 22, 34, 34, 23, 25, 23, 25, 30, 18, 21, 15, 23, 5, 35, 5, 
30), q2 = c(5, 5, 24, 15, 5, 5, 26, 23, 24, 9, 24, 5, 15, 26, 
30, 14, 14, 19, 11, 25, 20, 5, 14, 13, 11, 10, 13, 16, 16, 21, 
10, 12, 20, 9, 15, 5, 13, 5, 30, 18, 12, 27, 10, 9, 20, 5, 9, 
10, 11, 26, 22, 8, 6, 5, 15, 6, 5, 35, 10, 18), q3 = c(11, 22, 
NA, 22, 6, 18, 30, 6, 26, NA, 17, 22, 33, 19, 22, 25, 23, 13, 
13, 15, 16, 16, 23, 24, 6, 25, 27, 12, 25, 17, 28, 15, 20, 31, 
5, 17, 17, 20, 24, 7, 35, 35, 10, 10, 20, 10, 31, 21, 16, 32, 
25, 30, 10, 24, 15, 24, 5, 35, 9, 26), q4 = c(14, 15, 23, 21, 
NA, 25, 30, 23, 28, 20, 25, 5, 35, 30, 19, 23, 30, 5, 23, 18, 
30, 15, 30, 22, 8, 29, 35, 23, 23, 24, 25, 25, 20, 25, 5, 15, 
34, 8, 32, 35, 35, 35, 10, 6, 21, 10, 24, 27, 10, 30, 35, 15, 
6, 21, 15, 15, 5, 35, 19, 26), q5 = c(5, 18, 21, 19, 5, 6, 5, 
29, 20, 23, 22, 5, 16, 22, 12, 13, 18, 5, 17, 15, 18, 16, 20, 
8, 12, 19, 12, 23, 9, 16, 5, 29, 20, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 30, 22, 32, 
35, 10, 13, 20, 13, 12, 16, 5, 24, 22, 17, 5, 20, 14, 5, 5, 35, 
15, 16), q6 = c(15, 9, 25, 26, 6, 17, 28, 32, 26, 28, 24, 25, 
11, 24, 31, 18, 19, 6, 20, 26, 29, 17, 21, 24, 7, 29, 17, 17, 
14, 25, 24, 35, 24, 6, 16, 6, 9, 6, 38, 19, 30, 42, 12, 20, 27, 
26, 25, 13, 9, 36, 27, 27, 7, 24, 22, 6, 16, 42, 14, 11)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-60L))
```

I then use mice:

*edit: forgot the complete line

```
library(mice)
imp <- mice(example,m=5,maxit=50,meth='pmm',seed=500)
example_i <- complete(imp,1)
```

But when trying to get a densityplot I get the following error:

```
 densityplot(imp)
Error in str2lang(x) : <text>:2:0: unexpected end of input
1: ~
   ^
```

My questions are:

1. Is there something fundamentally wrong about my approach to impute missing data? (this is just a small example)
2. Am I using properly the MICE arguments?
3. What am I doing wrong with the density plot, as I have gotten it for all of the other scales I am working with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**

You need to supply a formula to `densityplot`, otherwise it will plot all variables with > 2 missing values. Since you don't have any variables with 2 > missing values, and since `densityplot` doesn't expect that, it produces this cryptic error.

---

**Example that works**

```r
example$q4[1:10] <- NA
imp <- mice(example, m = 5, maxit = 50, meth = "pmm", seed = 500)
densityplot(imp) 
# equivalent: densityplot(imp, ~ q4)
```

[image: density plot]

---

**Rationale**

`imp` is of class `mids`, so you are calling `densityplot.mids`. Normally, `densityplot.mids` requires you to provide a formula (`data` argument), so that it knows which variables to plot (see `?densityplot.mids`). If you want to plot `q4`, then the code is `densityplot(imp, ~ q4)`.

Inside `densityplot.mids`, we see:

```r
if (missing(data)) {
    vnames <- vnames[!allfactors & x$nmis > 2 & x$nmis < 
        nrow(x$data) - 1]
    formula <- as.formula(paste("~", paste(vnames, 
        collapse = "+", sep = ""), sep = ""))
}
```

If we use `traceback()` right after getting your error, then you will see that the last line above is the line that throws the error.

In the first line, you can see the condition `xnmis > 2`, which means that it will grab all the columns with more than 2 missing values. When no columns satisfy the conditions, then `vnames` will evaluate to `character(0)`, and so the subsequent line yields as output `~`, i.e. the code that you see in your error.

So, why does it give an error when there are too few missings? That's because `densityplot` plots a distribution, and plotting a distribution of 1 or 2 points is just not doable.

---

**Suggestion**

The package maintainers could improve the error by simply checking whether `vnames` has any content, and if not, they can throw an error that is informative. You may want to add this as [an issue on Github](https://github.com/amices/mice/issues) if you think it is useful.